# Drawing diagram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

can someone please help me get the same diagram as the picture. This is my first tentative using tikz. So, sorry if there were some obvious mistakes. I tried but the output does not come out the way I want it to. Thank you so much.
[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper, 12pt, french]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, top=3cm, headheight=26pt, headsep=25pt, heightrounded, showframe]{geometry}
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false} %more common footnote style
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} % footnote presentation
\usepackage[babel,french=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % level of section in titles printed in TOC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} %sectionning titles are numbered: level 5
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % nom du chapitre apparait en TOC
\graphicspath{{\images}}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, multirow, booktabs, hhline, caption}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{setspace} %interligne 1.5
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % espace entre deux paragraphes
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[explicit, clearempty]{titlesec}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{enumitem} % modifier et personaliser les puces des listes
\usepackage{pifont} % les symboles pour les listes
\usepackage[french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\AtBeginEnvironment{footcitedquote}{\singlespacing\small}
\AtBeginEnvironment{fancyquotes}{\small}
%\setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}}
\setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt} % show the hfull and underfull vbox hbox warning 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols}
\tikzset{
 >=stealth',
  punktchain/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, very thick,
  text width=16em, minimum height=3em, 
  text centered,on chain},
  line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
  element/.style={
  tape,
  top color=white,
  bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
  minimum width=8em,
  draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
  text width=10em, 
  minimum height=3.5em, 
  text centered, 
  on chain},
 every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
 decoration={brace},
 tuborg/.style={decorate},
 tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 [node distance=.8cm, start chain=going below,]
 \node[punktchain, join] {Etape 1: Identification du thème};
 \node[punktchain, join] {Etape 2: Revue de littérature};
 \node[punktchain, join] {Etape 3: Définition de la problèmatique};
 \node[punktchain, join] {Etape 4: Elaboration du design de recherche};
 \node[punktchain, join, ] {Etape 5: collecte des données};
 \node[punktchain, join, ] {Etape 6: Analyse des données};
   \node[punktchain, join, ] {Etape 7:  Résultats};

   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there, weren't you?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.8cm, start chain=going below,punktchain/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, very thick,
  text width=25em, minimum height=3em, 
  text centered,on chain},every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt}]
 \begin{scope}[nodes={join,punktchain}]
 \node (1) {Etape 1: Identification du th\`eme};
 \node[yshift=-1cm] (2)  {Etape 2: Revue de litt\'erature};
 \node (3) {Etape 3: D\'efinition de la probl\`ematique};
 \node (4)  {Etape 4: Elaboration du design de recherche};
 \node[yshift=-1cm] (5)  {Etape 5: collecte des donn\'ees};
 \node (6)  {Etape 6: Analyse des donn\'ees};
 \node (7)  {Etape 7:  R\'esultats};
 \end{scope} 
 \node[above=0.2em of 2,font=\itshape] (2l){Processus blablabla};
 \node[draw,fit=(2l)(4),inner xsep=1cm]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well I tried my best :) Thank you so much. I did some research about standalone do I have in order to put this code in my main file to add \usepackage{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit} in preambule of my main file and then Use \figure and \input{tikzcode}?

Comment: and can you please tell me how can I add some space between the word "processus" and the arrow?

Comment: @AlexiaColaud Yes, you can add it to the document in the way you describe. If you punch in the text you want to have (such that I do not have to punch it in from a screen shot, I will show how to add the gap.